# VSCode autocompletion adds extra information that I dont need/want with Haskell

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

Extra information is being added when autocomplete is used in VSCode and I do not know what setting is causing this to happen.

```
--Previous Output after autocomplete and what I want to happen after autocomplete:

map 

-- Current Output after autocomplete and what I NOT to happen after autocomplete:

map a -> b [a]
```

I am only using this extension with VSCode:

https://github.com/haskell/vscode-haskell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snippet completion is a feature recently added in haskell-language-server, the backend used by the vscode extension.
Unfortunately not always fits the user needs. We are in the process of being able to configure it and maybe make it opt-in.
You can track the progress here: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/issues/680

Comment: Next version of haskell-language-server (likely 0.9.0) will honour the configuration option that disables snippets: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/pull/1195